# MySql database Query solution?

Tags: mysql

There are 2 tables in my Database say 'si' and 'gi' and there is number column say regno in both the tables and I want to fetch data from both the tables.

And i am using this Mysql query

```
select * 
from si 
join gi on(si.regno=gi.regno) 
where regno=1"
```

and it is showing that `regno` is ambiguous.

What is the correct query for that?

Comment: Use fully qualified column name. In your particular case it could be either `si.regno ` or `gi.regno`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was error in **where** clause because which regno column from which table
 ,**si** or **gi**

change in your query

```
select *  from si join gi on(si.regno=gi.regno) where si.regno=1"
```

or

```
select *  from si join gi on(si.regno=gi.regno) where gi.regno=1"
```

Comment: Thanks @denny.
It was a very silly mistake I have.. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Build your query like this:
Try

```
SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        si
    INNER JOIN 
        gi 
    ON
        si.regno=gi.regno
    WHERE 
        where regno=1
```